# Fixing splintered wood on a curved surface

Tags: wood-repair, veneer

[image: Picture of first/huge splinter]

I received this 1926 La Vincdora Singer sewing machine in the mail a few days ago. It was sent to me in pristine condition so I have filed a claim. My question is. Is it possible to fix these areas that have splintered from damage (most likely being dropped). I am already planning on sanding or stripping it and staining it to bring it back to its past glory.

As per requested, I am adding more photos of the splinters from the inside. I was in no way insinuating that this isn't veneered. I know that it is. My problem is that the splinters go all the way through the veneer into the inside of the case.

(sorry I had to remove one photo to add another.
[image: This is the inside of where the first splinter comes through]

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The cracks you're looking at are in a layer of "veneer".  This is a very thin sheet of wood that is glued onto a substrate to improve the visual appearance of the piece.  Unfortunately veneer is notoriously difficult to repair without redoing the entire surface.  The fact that the damage is to a curved surface makes any repair even more difficult.

Comment: this is actually all the way through. it's not just on a veneer layer. this case was probably made back in 1926 when the sewing machine it is for was made.

Comment: *"I am already planning on sanding it and staining it to bring it back to its past glory."* I would strongly recommend you don't sand off the previous finish. Sanding is the worst way to remove old finish anyway and would be very bad indeed if the repair is not already complete. Scraping is *far* preferable for removing old finish (far faster, cheaper, much better) if you don't use chemical means, i.e. a stripper of some kind. In this case you shouldn't need a strong stripper if it hasn't been refinished before, there's every change it's done in shellac which is permanently soluble in alcohol.

Comment: From the photographs I would take this to be a veneer crack also, literally the first thing I thought. In fact I think I can tell you that it's rotary-cut veneer from its appearance (one of the mahoganies). The date of this doesn't at all rule out veneering, it was very common through the entire 19th century to use veneers in specific circumstances and by the early 20th it had become an established way of giving the look of expensive woods on pieces of modest cost, by using thin sheets of nice wood on cheaper woods such as pine or oak, for the burgeoning middle class.

Comment: Now about the repair, I think we need more photos to be able to help properly but actually I think this isn't the best venue for you to seek help on this as you'll need some back and forth that SE is not set up to provide. You'd be better off posting on a conventional forum where you can post the initial question (with more photos, showing the inside as well as the outside), get clarification on the replies and then post stage-by-stage pics of the progress for further input as needed.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding re. the use of veneer. Now about the repair, I'm afraid this may not be repairable in a strong and stable way without significant intervention. Since you can't just glue down a layer of wood to a base layer because the break goes all the way through this needs to be reinforced somehow, and I think the only good route is bonding to another layer of ply, which is a fairly specialist operation and not something I would take on. Arguably the best option is actually complete replacement of the broken piece :-(